# Status bar issue in Portrait mode

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

I have an 2 `ViewController` first `ViewController` in Portrait mode and `SecondViewController` in Landscape mode. used category to `SecondViewController` in LandScapemode.

My requirement is my `SecondViewController` Status bar in landscape mode i want it to Portrait mode. how may i do this

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait animated:NO];
```

i have tried this line of code but not work how may i do this

thanks in advance.

Comment: You could maybe find an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18424846/force-portrait-mode?rq=1

Comment: i want view in landScape but status bar in Portrait mode.

Comment: please help me anybody if know this answer...